# WPF Convert TextBox Text using IValueConverter

Tags: c#, wpf, ivalueconverter

I want to implement a IValueConverter class, which converts text from textBox to TimeSpan format string. And further if user inputs simple number, it should be converted to TimeSpan, eg. 65.8 -> 0:01:05.800

The converter works fine, it is called after each keystroke, thus if I want to write 65.8, it is converted to 0:00:06 immediately.

What is wrong?

**IValueConverter**
*Note that Solver is static class, where the time format is checked etc., this works properly*

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {

            string time = (string)value;
            TimeSpan _ts = new TimeSpan();
            if (Solver.OnlySeconds(time, out _ts))
            {
                return _ts.ToString(Solver.__TFORMAT);
            }
            else return time;
        }
        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return (string)value;
        }
```

**XAML**

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtTime" Width="100" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                 Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource self},Path=Text, Converter={StaticResource ConvertToTime}, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"/>
```

**Solver**

```
 public class Solver
    {
        #region constants
        /// <summary>
        /// Output TimeSpan format
        /// </summary>
        public const string __TFORMAT = @"%h\:mm\:ss\.fff";
        /// <summary>
        /// hours and minutes separator
        /// </summary>
        public const string __COL = ":";
        /// <summary>
        /// Negative sign
        /// </summary>
        public const string __NEG = "-";
        private const int __PREC = 1000; //determines precision to 1/1000 of second
        private const long __SECTOTICK = 10000000;
        #endregion
        /// <summary>
        /// Determines if value is convertable to seconds and creates new TimeSpan
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="time">Time</param>
        /// <param name="TS">out, timeSpan representing Time value</param>
        /// <returns>True if succesfull, false if not</returns>
        #region public Methods
        public static bool OnlySeconds(string time, out TimeSpan TS)
        {
            double dSeconds;

            if (Double.TryParse(time, out dSeconds))
            {
                long ticks = (long)(dSeconds * __SECTOTICK);
                TS = new TimeSpan(ticks);
                return true;
            }
            TS = new TimeSpan();
            return false;

        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Determines if value is valid TimeSpan Format
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="time">Time</param>
        /// <param name="TS">out TimeSpan value alwas with 0 days</param>
        /// <returns>true if conversions succesfull</returns>
        public static bool IsTimeValue(string time, out TimeSpan TS)
        {
            TimeSpan _ts = new TimeSpan();
            if (OnlySeconds(time,out TS))
            {
                return true;
            }
            if (TimeSpan.TryParse(time,out _ts))
            {
                TS = determineTimeFromString(time);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        #endregion
        #region private methods
        /// <summary>
        /// Converts selected string to TImeSpan. String has to be in valid TimeSpan format. Erases days
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sTime">Time</param>
        /// <returns>Time span</returns>
        private static TimeSpan determineTimeFromString(string sTime)
        {

                int _iColon = Regex.Matches(sTime, __COL).Count;
                string _sResult;
                TimeSpan _tsDays = new TimeSpan();

                if (TimeSpan.TryParse(sTime, out _tsDays))
                {
                    if (_tsDays.Days > 0)
                        return new TimeSpan(0, _tsDays.Hours, _tsDays.Minutes, _tsDays.Seconds, _tsDays.Milliseconds);
                }



                TimeSpan _ts = new TimeSpan();
                if (_iColon == 1) //minutes and seconds
                {
                    //add 0 hours and 0 days
                    _sResult = addTimeToTimeSpan(sTime, "0.0:");
                }
                else if
                  (_iColon == 2) //hours minutes and seconds
                {

                    //add 0 days
                    _sResult = addTimeToTimeSpan(sTime, "0.");
                }
                else _sResult = sTime;

                if (TimeSpan.TryParse(_sResult, out _ts))
                {
                    // in all cases remove day 
                    return new TimeSpan(0, _ts.Hours, _ts.Minutes, _ts.Seconds, _ts.Milliseconds);
                }
                else return _ts;


        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Adds time days or hours to time string
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sTime">string original time</param>
        /// <param name="sTimeToAdd">string to ADD</param>
        /// <returns>string</returns>
        private static string addTimeToTimeSpan(string sTime, string sTimeToAdd)
        {
            string _sResult;
            if (sTime.StartsWith(__NEG))
            {
                _sResult = __NEG + sTimeToAdd + sTime.Remove(0, 1);
            }
            else _sResult = sTimeToAdd + sTime;
            return _sResult;
        }
        #endregion region

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure, that `Solver` works correct? Please, share `OnlySeconds` and `__TFORMAT` members. It seems, that you have something incorrect inside this members

Comment: I am pretty sure it works correct. But publishing. My problem is the converter is triggered after each keystroke. I do not want to use events, because I am planning use this converter further on DataGrid for certain columns.

Comment: I think you need to add your binding `Delay=500` for debounce.

Comment: @JanOttis try to use `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` in `TextBox` binding

Comment: Sorry, none of your suggestion worked

Comment: @JanOttis Why do you need this kind of `Text` binding `{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource self},Path=Text`? Why just don't use `{Binding Text}`?

Comment: That was my first attempt. But in this case IValueConverter is never called

Comment: Please, share the data context of the view, where the `TextBox` is declared

Comment: You're binding the text to itself. This is a bad idea. Partly because it's a twoway binding by default so of course your source is changing as you type. You'd have more chance of this working if it's bound to a viewmodel property.

Comment: Yes Andy, I am a fool. I believe BionicCode below shows my approach is totally wrong.

Comment: There's a lot to learn with wpf.  I think you'd have to spend so much time researching you'd never get anything done if you tried to totally avoid bad choices on your first app. That was my excuse anyhow :^)

Answer (score 0):

You should create an Attached Behavior to convert `TextBox.Text` on `TextBox.LostFocus`:

**TextBox.cs**

```
public class TextBox : DependencyObject
{
  #region IsTextConversionEnabled attached property

  public static readonly DependencyProperty IsTextConversionEnabledProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
    "IsTextConversionEnabled", 
    typeof(bool), 
    typeof(TextBox), 
    new PropertyMetadata(false, TextBox.OnIsTextConversionEnabledChanged));

  public static void SetIsTextConversionEnabled([NotNull] DependencyObject attachingElement, bool value) => attachingElement.SetValue(TextBox.IsTextConversionEnabledProperty, value);

  public static bool GetIsTextConversionEnabled([NotNull] DependencyObject attachingElement) => (bool) attachingElement.GetValue(TextBox.IsTextConversionEnabledProperty);

  #endregion

  #region Converter attached property

  public static readonly DependencyProperty ConverterProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
    "Converter", 
    typeof(IValueConverter), 
    typeof(TextBox), 
    new PropertyMetadata(default(IValueConverter)));

  public static void SetConverter([NotNull] DependencyObject attachingElement, IValueConverter value) => attachingElement.SetValue(TextBox.ConverterProperty, value);

  public static IValueConverter GetConverter([NotNull] DependencyObject attachingElement) => (IValueConverter) attachingElement.GetValue(TextBox.ConverterProperty);

  #endregion

  private static void OnIsTextConversionEnabledChanged(DependencyObject attachingElement, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    if (!(attachingElement is System.Windows.Controls.TextBox textBox))
    {
      return;
    }

    bool isEnabled = (bool) e.NewValue;
    if (isEnabled)
    {
      textBox.LostFocus += TextBox.ConvertTextOnLostFocus;
    }
    else
    {
      textBox.LostFocus -= TextBox.ConvertTextOnLostFocus;
    }
  }

  private static void ConvertTextOnLostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    var textBox = sender as System.Windows.Controls.TextBox;
    textBox.Text = TextBox.GetConverter(textBox)?.Convert(
      textBox.Text,
      typeof(string),
      string.Empty,
      CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture) as string ?? textBox.Text;
  }
}
```

**Usage**

```
<Resources>

  <!-- Your IValueConverter implementation -->
  <DoubleToTimeStampConverter x:Key="DoubleToTimeStampConverter" />
</Resources>

<TextBox TextBox.IsTextConversionEnabled="True" 
         TextBox.Converter="{StaticResource DoubleToTimeStampConverter}" />
```

An alternative solution would be to extend `TextBox` and handle the `LostFocus` event internally.

Comment: Thank you very much Madam or Sir, that worked perfectly. More important is that I am starting to understand (may be) wpf approach. My original question and idea (approach) is wrong. Jan